# Usando require, aonde usar essa tag?

Tags: php, html, require

Tinah feito essa pergunta antes, mas não fui tão específico dai decidi reformular aqui colocando o meu código para que entendam melhor.
Aqui eu tenho o arquivo principal que será usado como modelo para todas as páginas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<title>Guia Norte Capixaba</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="img/guianortecapixaba.ico" type="image/gif" sizes="42x42">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
    .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
        background-color: #7faec3;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .sidenav {
            height: auto;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        .row.content {height:auto;}
    }
</style>
</head>


<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost:8888/GuiaNorteCapixaba" target="_self">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Cadastre-se Gratuitamente</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!--Aqui o cabeçalho do portal-->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="img/header-template.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100%">

</div>

</div>
<!--Fim do cabeçalho do portal-->

<!--Barra esquerda-->

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <img src="img/banner-divulgacao.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Divulgação" width="100%">

        </div>
<!--Essa é a página central-->

<div class="col-sm-8 text-left">

    <h3>O que você esta procurando? Digite aqui:</h3>
    <form class="form-inline" action="busca.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite aqui..." name="palavra">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cidade">Selecione a cidade:</label>
            <select name="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade">
                <option value="sao-gabriel-da-palha">São Gabriel da Palha</option>
                <option value="sao-domingos-do-norte">São Domingos do Norte</option>
                <option value="vila-valerio">Vila Valério</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
        </div>

<!--fim da página central-->

        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <img src="img/banner-divulgacao-2.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Divulgação" width="100%">
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Desenvolvido por <a href="https://andreyferraz.com" target="_blank">Andrêy Ferraz</a> </p>
</footer>
</html>
```

Dai aqui eu tenho uma página chamada sobre.php na qual eu estou chamando esse modelo via require, portanto o conteúdo da minha página não esta ficando no corpo onde devia, mas sim após o footer, como resolver isso? Aqui a página sobre:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <title>Guia Norte Capixaba</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/guianortecapixaba.ico" type="image/gif" sizes="42x42">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
        .row.content {height: 450px}

        /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
        .sidenav {
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
        footer {
            background-color: #7faec3;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .sidenav {
                height: auto;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .row.content {height:auto;}
        }

    </style>
    <?php
    require 'principal.php';
    ?>
</head>


<body>


<!--Fim do cabeçalho do portal-->

<!--Barra esquerda-->

        <!--Essa é a página central-->


            <p>aqui entra o meu texto</p>


        <!--fim da página central-->
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Aqui como o arquivo ta ficando, o texto teria que aparecer no centro abaixo do formulário]

Comment: Não pode incluir no sitio que está a incluir nem com o conteudo que está a incluir. Se imaginar o html que vem da página `principal.php` e assumindo que é a primeira que mostra, colocado onde tem o `require`, vai ficar com duas etiquetas `<body>`, etc, e por isso com um documento incorreto. Tem de segmentar a página em blocos e incluir apenas cada pedaço no sitio certo

Comment: @Isac muito obrigado pela informação, mais eu ainda estou aprendendo teria como você me mostrar ai como ficaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPfan,

Você não pode chamar um require que resulte duas tags   .

Num exemplo esdrúxulo, seria mesma coisa que duas pessoas tentando vestir a mesma camiseta.

Imagine seu HTML como um quebra cabeça e o require como o encaixe desse quebra cabeça.

Então, sugiro que você faça um footer.php e um header.php separados da suas páginas sobre.php e principal.php

Porque?

Porque ai você elimina o erro do seu require. Acontece que você está chamando a principal.php dentro da tag  da sua página sobre.php e isso está fazendo com que o navegador se perca na hora de ler o HTML.

Sugiro o seguinte:

Crie os arquivos 
header.php;
footer.php;
principal.php;

Dentro de header.php adicione:

```
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <title>Guia Norte Capixaba</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/guianortecapixaba.ico" type="image/gif" sizes="42x42">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
        .row.content {height: 450px}

        /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
        .sidenav {
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
        footer {
            background-color: #7faec3;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .sidenav {
                height: auto;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .row.content {height:auto;}
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
```

Dentro de footer.php adicione:

```
<!--fim da página central-->

        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <img src="img/banner-divulgacao-2.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Divulgação" width="100%">
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Desenvolvido por <a href="https://andreyferraz.com" target="_blank">Andrêy Ferraz</a> </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

E dentro do seu principal.php assim:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost:8888/GuiaNorteCapixaba" target="_self">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Cadastre-se Gratuitamente</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!--Aqui o cabeçalho do portal-->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="img/header-template.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100%">

</div>

</div>
<!--Fim do cabeçalho do portal-->

<!--Barra esquerda-->

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <img src="img/banner-divulgacao.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Divulgação" width="100%">

        </div>
<!--Essa é a página central-->

<div class="col-sm-8 text-left">

    <h3>O que você esta procurando? Digite aqui:</h3>
    <form class="form-inline" action="busca.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite aqui..." name="palavra">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cidade">Selecione a cidade:</label>
            <select name="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade">
                <option value="sao-gabriel-da-palha">São Gabriel da Palha</option>
                <option value="sao-domingos-do-norte">São Domingos do Norte</option>
                <option value="vila-valerio">Vila Valério</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
```

Lá no sobre.php você junta todas as páginas que quer deste modo:

```
require 'header.php';
require 'principal.php';
<p>aqui entra o seu texto</p>
require 'footer.php';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, isso foi muito útil.. agora vou testar aqui!

Comment: mesmo assim continua imprimindo o texto no lugar errado

Comment: posta uma foto de onde ta saindo o texto e onde você queria que ficasse

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei a imagem. Veja que o texto foi impresso no canto inferior esquerdo, quando que deveria ser impresso abaixo do formulário de busca

Comment: O texto foi adicionando corretamente, o que está errado é como foi feito o desmembramento do html. Vou editar a pergunta para com a resposta para solucionar o seu problema

Comment: mudou o footer.php e o principal.php, veja se resolve.

Comment: agora bagunçou foi tudo... não entendo porque isso está tão complicado

Comment: Resolvido, tive que criar um require para cada div, ou seja para cada bloco!